# MYSQL How to show most popular items in the last two days

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to show the most popular items in the last two days, but this view is letting in items that happened over two days ago.

It is made to find the most popular in the last two days (maybe 20-30 items) and fill the remaining ones with random items (need 1000 items on the view at all times)

How can I fix this?

Thank you

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `XX`@`XX` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `trending` AS
    select 
        `question`.`name` AS `name`,
        `question`.`questionUrl` AS `questionUrl`,
        `question`.`miRating` AS `miRating`,
        `question`.`imageUrl` AS `imageUrl`,
        `question`.`miThumbnail` AS `miThumbnail`,
        `question`.`foundOn` AS `foundOn`,
        `question`.`myId` AS `myId`
    from
        (`question`
        join `feed` ON ((`question`.`myId` = `feed`.`question_id`)))
    group by `question`.`name`
    order by (`feed`.`timeStamp` >= (now() - interval 1 day)) desc , 
    (`feed`.`question_id` is not null) desc , 
    (((`question`.`likesCount` * 0.8) + (`question`.`commentsCount` * 0.6)) + ((`question`.`sharesCount` * 1) / 2.4)) desc
    limit 0 , 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are grouping by `question_name`, but you have a lot of other columns in the query, in both the `select` and the `order by`.  MySQL chooses arbitrary values for these.  One way to fix this is by using only the maximum of the time condition in the `order by` clause:

```
select q.`name` AS `name`, q.`questionUrl` AS `questionUrl`, q.`miRating` AS `miRating`,
       q.`imageUrl` AS `imageUrl`, q.`miThumbnail` AS `miThumbnail`,
       q.`foundOn` AS `foundOn`, q.`myId` AS `myId`
from `question` q join
     `feed` f
      ON q.`myId` = f.`question_id`
group by q.`name`
order by (max(f.`timeStamp`) >= (now() - interval 1 day)) desc , 
         (f.`question_id` is not null) desc , 
         (((q.`likesCount` * 0.8) + (q.`commentsCount` * 0.6)) + ((q.`sharesCount` * 1) / 2.4)) desc
limit 0 , 1000
```

Comment: Should I group by something else? Like timestamp?

Comment: Also, I just changed it, but I still see a question at the top that hasn't had any activity in the last two days. Maybe the overall method isn't appropriate for this. Maybe don't weight the social component, and just do time interval?

Comment: @waf . . . Grouping by `timestamp` could also work, if you don't mind having the questions appear multiple times.  The `max()` should only have questions within the last *day* at the top, because of the `- interval 1 day`.